# Access Beacon Frame Information from Android

Tags: android, networking, wifi

Is it possible to read the information provided by Access Points in their periodically sent beacon frames? 
Or is it possible to at least monitor beacon frames at all?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I'm looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, otherwise why would it be sent in the first place?..
That's exactly what WiFi driver does. If you want to have this info in your application, you must configure your driver to sniffer mode (if supported) and install some kind of sniffing application such as `wireshark`.